# Change the icons of PrimeFaces p:rating?

Tags: css, primefaces, rating

I would like to change the shape of `p:rating`.. And display circles or squares or anything else instead of the stars. Is it possible. Maybe by CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## You have two Options

### Option 1

You need to create your own icons, basiclly the icons are in one [sprite image](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/rating/rating.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.0.4):

[image: original image]

So in your case you would implement your own by replacing each icon, for example:

[image]

Then in CSS replace the background with the new one:

```
div.ui-rating-star a, div.ui-rating-cancel a {
  background-image: url("#{resource['images/icon/myrating.png']}");                       
}
```

[online demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/rating/main.xhtml)

#### How to create such sprites

go to http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/

Select

[image: change size]

Then

[image: size]

Create your icons 15x15px
[image: like this]

Drag and drop to the pad
[image: drag]

### Option 2

Font-awesome or any other css font

```
<p:rating styleClass="awesome-rating" />
```

in case of font-awesome you need to add this css piece

```css
.awesome-rating .ui-rating-star, .awesome-rating  .ui-rating-cancel {
    float: initial;
    display: inline;
}

.awesome-rating .ui-rating-star a, .awesome-rating  .ui-rating-cancel a {
    background: none;
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline;
}

.awesome-rating  .ui-rating-cancel a:before {
    content: "\f056";
}

.awesome-rating  .ui-rating-cancel.ui-rating-cancel-hover a {
    color: #ce1c18;
}

.awesome-rating .ui-rating-star a:before {
    content: "\f006";
}

.awesome-rating .ui-rating-star.ui-rating-star-on a {
    color: #fadc3e;
}

.awesome-rating .ui-rating-star.ui-rating-star-on a:before {
    content: "\f005";
}
```

you can change the `:before` content with the icons content code, here's a [full list](https://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

**See more:**

- [CSS Image
  Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much :) it worked. But have you an online solution to create my own sprite plz?

Comment: XD I googled while waiting your answer and found the same site. I created my sprite. thank you :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did :) normally I use Photoshop so I had no idea such sites existed. You're welcome.

Comment: Is an update for PF 13 how to do the same. Because that is seems  not working for PF13 .